# Different Facebook Pixels Across Funnel - Affiliates

Tags: wordpress, facebook, affiliate, facebook-pixel

What is the best way to set up different Facebook pixels across a funnel?

We have a small "in-house", affiliate network we would like to set up. Each affiliate has a referring URL and each affiliate will have its own FB pixels used for remarketing.

I would like to use GTM to deploy a Facebook pixel.

The funnel is:

```
-> Landing Page (page view FB pixel) 
-> Subscribe Page or Pre Sale page (another page view FB pixel)
-> Cart (another page view FB pixel)
-> Thank You or Confirmation Page (conversion FB pixel)
```

We can easily assign pixels to each page, but we would like the pixel associated with the affiliate to trigger.

ie: There are two affiliates, Sam and John. Sam's pixel should only trigger throughout the funnel for his referrals. And only Johns's pixel should trigger throughout the funnel for his referrals.

What is the best way to achieve this? Our goal is to allow for each affiliate to use their pixels for retargeting.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this. The solutions we are deploying will be using Google Tag Manager (GTM) and cookies.

Each affiliate will have its own referring URL. When someone enters the website through that URL we search for a cookie containing a specific value. We will trigger the specific Facebook pixel for that value.

We have a manageable list of affiliates so tracking and setting this up will not be overwhelming.

The other solution would be to build a funnel for each affiliate.